# Distance calculated via Google Distance Matrix API and Google Map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-distancematrix-api

I have an application where distance between two points received via API is different than that of when checked on google map app. This API has a direct monetary impact on business.

eg: Using API https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=13.13212951,80.24748131&destinations=12.9593040,80.2450580&mode=driving

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "Plot No. 1, Developed Industrial Estate Near Perungudi Toll Plaza, Perungudi, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600096, India"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "Mosque, Teacher's Colony, Kodungaiyur, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600118, India"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "23.9 km",
                  "value" : 23921
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 hour 1 min",
                  "value" : 3680
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

But than using google map

[image]

I need a way to find the distance coved via optimal route

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why don't you check the requests and corresponding parameters Googe Maps site is passing? On the Developer tab under Network traffic?

Comment: The DistanceMatrix and Google Maps are different things.  Why do you expect them to return the same result?  Have you tried comparing the DirectionsService result to see if it returns the same route?

Comment: After every 24 km traveled I charge double charge from the client. For example, when I call the API I get 23.9 km but the actual traveled distance is 26.7 km so the actual change should be 2x, but unfortunately my service is per-paid, so later I can't really increase price after the task is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this issue is the same with what is reported in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/133083921), based on the answer in the issue:

> Please note that Google Maps and Google Maps API are two different
>   products of Google and is not guaranteed to return the exact same
>   results, Google Maps and Google Maps APIs gather data from different
>   sources that's why it will most likely to return different results
>   from each other as they also have different back end processes. We
>   would suggest that you rely more on Google Maps API as those will be
>   the one that will be used in your implementation. Should you encounter
>   any data issues, kindly use the "Report a Problem" or "Send feedback"
>   link on the bottom right corner on maps.google.com or in the Google
>   Maps for Mobile Application. To learn more, please see
>   https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088

This means that users should not rely on the result that is being returned by the API to be an exact match of the result of the Google Maps as they have different sources of data.